# IIS6 Config - Long Running Requests

Tags: iis-6, asp-classic

I am looking for advice on config changes we might make to help aliviate what seems to be a small scale attack on so old classic asp pages on a site we are hosting.

The user in question opens several requests for these classic pages but not in huge volumes no more than 400 requests in 30 mins. The request take about 1.5 to 2 seconds to run and then enter the send data phase. They then sit in this phase and the queue builds up. Eventually we are not able to process more requests as there are too many of these requests queuing. The queueing is occuring after the request is complete so we are not waiting on the database or other resource here.

Connection Timeout is set to 120 seconds (is this too long)

MinFileBytesPerSecond is set to 360. The page in question is 20KB so by my calculation this allows a max 27 seconds to download the page. Is this too long?

ASPProcessorTheadMax is set to 75 this is high but CPU is not maxed out, it is above the 50% guidline when the queuing occurs.

Any thoughts greatfully received.

Comment: What do you mean by "and then enter the send data phase."?

Answer (score 0):

Having a high ASPprocessorThreadMax value actually complicates the problem because more things are queued while threaded tasks wait to complete. It can also cause problems with session states when the worker process has threads waiting and finishing in different orders per page request.

Have you looked at what the ASP code is doing? In my experience working in hosting, badly written code is the cause of most performance/bottleneck issues.